# How to do 'git checkout --theirs' for multiple files (or all unmerged files)

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-add

Say I have this after attempting a merge and upon entering `git status`:

```
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   added by them: myfile1.xhtml
#   added by them: myfile2.xhtml
#   added by them: myfile3.xhtml
```

... and I know I want to do this for each of those files:

```
git checkout --theirs myfile1.xhtml
git add myfile1.xhtml
```

... but there are many of them. How might I do them as a batch?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The solution for my case ended up being to simply use a wildcard in the directory path, since the files were grouped:

```
git checkout --theirs directory_name/*
git add directory_name/*
```

This may also work, according to [helios456](https://stackoverflow.com/users/177789/helios456):

```
git checkout --theirs directory_name/.
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the below commands to checkout multiples files on unmerged path

```
git checkout --theirs `git status | grep "added by them:" | awk '{print $NF}'`
```

execute the below command to commit the above files

```
git commit `git status | grep "added by them:" | awk '{print $NF}'`
```

Answer (score 4):

If your files are deeper than one directory (ie. there are subdirectories) and you want to selectively recursively choose all `their` files for a directory, then use the following:

```
grep -lr '<<<<<<<' directory_name/ | xargs git checkout --theirs
git add directory_name/*
```

(From an [article on handling merge conflicts](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/git/git-resolve-merge-conflicts/).)

Comment: This doesn't work if there are binary files present, though.

Answer (score 2):

This checks out all unmerged files without specifying the directory:

```
git ls-files --unmerged | perl -n -e'/\t(.*)/ && print "$1\n"' | uniq | xargs -r git checkout --theirs --
```

[Source](https://snipt.net/binjured/git-checkout-theirs-for-all-unmerged/)

Comment: This answer would be better with some explanation of all those arguments and flags.

Answer (score -1):

Use **Folder/.** instead

This simple solution worked for me!

So basically check what is the root folder for your project, in case it is called **src**, you can add them all like this:

```
git checkout --theirs src/.
```

Comment: How does this add to the accepted answer? It's also a repeat of an answer you deleted. Why wouldn't you simply undelete that one?