# TortoiseGit: Mark as merged multiple files

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have a conflict with the head and I need to merge 100s of files. I would like to merge all the files in bulk. I know I want what is in the head (not what I have).

I select all the checkboxes and right click and **"Resolve Conflict Using Theirs"**. However only one file is resolved.

This basically means i need to do one file at a time (100s of times).

Is there a better way, because I can think of 273 better things to do with my time.

[image]

Comment: IIRC, it's an issue, but fixed. What is the version of TortoiseGit?

Comment: TortoiseGit 1.8.16.0

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly straightforward to do from the Git bash:

```
git checkout --theirs src/pages/*
git add src/pages/*
git commit -m 'merged and resolve conflict'
```

If you have conflicted files in other paths, then you can use a similar command.  From your screen capture, this method might work well for you, as your conflicted files seem to be grouped together in a common root folder.

I give credit to [this great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916186/how-to-do-git-checkout-theirs-for-multiple-files-or-all-unmerged-files%5C) which discusses a similar problem to yours.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in TortoiseGit which was just [fixed](https://tortoisegit.org/issue/2655) (fix is in 2.0.0).

As a temporary workaround using the command line, please see the answer of [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35081154/3906760).