# How Can I resolve conflicts with git command line to keep target (visual studio 2019)?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

when merging with git there are a lot of conflicts, I just want to Keep target or take source - is there a way to do this from UI or git command line so I can do them for multiple/all files?  thank you.  Visual studio used to allow us to do with TFVC repos.

[image]

Edit: note - that I don't want to use -Xtheirs or -Xours on git command line, because I dont necessarily want all the files in the merge to be auto merged with ours or theirs - I would want to choose which files (or first merge some of the files differently so what's left would either be auto merged as ours or theirs). is there a command or way to do this in UI to do this AFTER the merge command and not part of the merge command so I can first choose different merge for other files.

Comment: you want auto merging ?

Comment: no i want to choose either take source, or keep target for all files

Answer (score 2):

**using -Xours or -Xtheirs parameter in merge command you solve this issue**

```
git merge -Xours merging_branch_name
```

**OR**

```
git merge -Xtheirs merging_branch_name
```

[for details follow this link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging)

Comment: thanks for reply but not really what i want.  I dont necessarily want all the files in the merge to be auto merged with ours or theirs - I would want to choose which files (or first merge some of the files differently so what's left would either be auto merged as ours or theirs).  is there a command to do this AFTER the merge command and not part of the merge command so I can first choose different merge for other files? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`git checkout [--ours|--theirs]`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem-f--ours--theirs-m--conflictltstylegtlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203) on a list of files or directories :

```
git checkout --ours -- file1
git checkout --theirs -- file2
git add file1 file2

# you can specify any number of patterns :
git checkout --ours -- file1 file2 dir3/ that/dir/too/
```

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916186/how-to-do-git-checkout-theirs-for-multiple-files-or-all-unmerged-files